# Angular 13 - How can I check array length before rendering using <mat-accordion> and <mat-expansion> and ngIf and ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I had try this code but it is not work:

**TS:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: 'post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['post-list.component.css'],
})
export class PostListComponent {

  posts = [];
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ post.title }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

<p *ngIf="posts.length == 0">No posts</p>
```

**The error:**

Initial Chunk Files | Names   | Raw Size
main.js             | main    | 20.68 kB |
runtime.js          | runtime |  6.52 kB |

3 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2022-02-17T12:49:32.171Z - Hash: 942ee67818541d4c - Time: 170ms

Error: src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component.html:6:15 - error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'never'.

6       {{ post.title }}
~~~~~

src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: 'post-list.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component PostListComponent.

Error: src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component.html:8:16 - error TS2339: Property 'content' does
not exist on type 'never'.

8

{{ post.content }}

~~~~~~~

src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: 'post-list.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component PostListComponent.

Comment: This should work. Maybe try defining your posts variable as:
`posts: any[] = [];`

Comment: yes it's work I put posts: any[] = [];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable type checking in template like explained here :- https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#disabling-type-checking-using-any

Your source code would look like :-

```
<mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      {{ $any(post).title }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>{{ $any(post).content }}</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>

<p *ngIf="posts.length == 0">No posts</p>
```